# Report only the first hibernate validation constraint

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, constraints

I have a field on which I use hibernate constrain validations.

```
@NotEmpty
@Email
@Pattern(regexp=".+@.+\\..+", message = "error")
private String email;
```

I want to be able to return the @NotEmpty message but wihout also the following (for @Pattern for example).
I found @ReportAsSingleViolation, but IDEA tells me is 'not applicable to field'

Answer (score 0):

```
@Target(value=ANNOTATION_TYPE)
@Retention(value=RUNTIME)
public @interface ReportAsSingleViolation
```

says that is should be used on type (class) not on field. Try it out.